# Is it safe to use an old fridge after 14 years of non use?

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

Recently our fridge broke. We have a working one in the kitchen, standing upright in the same position in the kitchen for 14 years, it just hasn't been plugged in during that amount of time. It's clean inside and out and was working fine last time it was on 14 years ago. I live in Britain so it never really gets that humid here except for a month or so every year in the summer.

Is it safe to use and should I expect any problems with it?

Comment: >Britain.   >never gets humid here.  Wait.  Isn't "the damp" infamously British?

Comment: I've been told that an idle refrigerator will have seals dried out in the compressor since the oil settles.  If true, don't expect it to last long.

Answer (score 1):

The only safety concern I'd have would be if it was stored some place where critters could have got in and chewed up the wiring. That doesn't seem to be the case here. Plug it in and see if it works.

From a health point of view you should obviously clean it really well.

Answer (score 1):

I would be concerned about the mold and mildew that has grown in the evaporator coil and fan area.  I doubt if if could be cleaned to a satisfactory level.  Much of this space is not available to the end user.  The smell alone I suspect would render it untenable.  My vote is no.

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe, since you said it was clean it should be safe. What problems can be expected? If it runs and cools down it should be fine and other than door seals there should be no problems. I would plug it in and put some water in the freezer if you get ice it is ready to use, if it won't freeze the refredgrant probably needs a recharge.